# Aggregate initialization of array of structs using array

Tags: c++, arrays, aggregate-initialization

In C++ (14/17), how do you initialize a (large) array of structs without a hardcoded brace-enclosed list of initializors?

For example, what do you do if you need a large number of initialization or you don't know the initialization values until run time? There doesn't seem to be a post about this. I've created a simple example of what I was hoping to do. Hopefully someone can explain how this can be done:

```
struct myStruct
{
  int value;    

  myStruct(int input)
  { 
    value = input*input;
  }
};

int main()
{
  // option #1 - aggregate initialization
  myStruct array1[] {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}};

  // option #2 - using available array (??)
  int input[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};  
  myStruct array2[] { input[] } ;  // something like this?

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, single initializer for all, or incremental per member?

Comment: It's not possible to use a C-style array as initializer in place of a braced list of that array's elements.  I'm not sure if there is any way you can guarantee compile-time initialization of a container with 1,2,3,4,5 and also initialization of array2 with the values of the container

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the size of the array until run time, the container to use is `std::vector<myStruct>`. However, to do that, you need to have a default constuctor in `myStruct`.

You can use `std::transform` to construct `myStruct` objects from `int` values and populate the `std::vector`.

Demonstrative code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct myStruct
{
   int value;    

   myStruct() : myStruct(0) {}

   myStruct(int input)
   { 
      value = input*input;
   }
};

int main()
{
   // option #2 - using available array (??)
   int input[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};  
   int size = sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input);

   // array2 has to be of the right size before the call to std::transform
   // std::transform does not call push_back. It simply assigns the value to
   // the dereferenced iterator.
   std::vector<myStruct> array2(size);

   std::transform(std::begin(input),
                  std::end(input),
                  array2.begin(),
                  [](int v) -> myStruct { return myStruct(v); });


   return(0);
}
```

---

The default constructor of `myStruct` can be avoided by using `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct myStruct
{
   int value;    

   myStruct(int input)
   { 
      value = input*input;
   }
};

int main()
{
   int input[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};  

   // Create an empty vector.
   std::vector<myStruct> array2;

   // Add items to the vector by using std::copy and std::back_inserter.
   std::copy(std::begin(input),
             std::end(input),
             std::back_inserter(array2));

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: The demonstrative code is already really helpful - thank you! It works perfectly. I figured out M.M's comment, too. I very nicely allows you to remove the default constructor and it works perfect once you define the std::vector<myStruct> array2; without size. Many thanks J.